Tampermonkey paste from clipboard
I'm trying to automate a task in a weird internal web application. It's http not (s) and clipboard API is not supported, document.execcommand('paste') is also not working. For now I'm using listener for paste event, but I'd like to eliminate any user input. Any ideas?
    // Function to automate
function RD01() {
        // Activity input element
        let actElement = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_CphContentWrapper_CphMainContent_DocumentEditor_SelectActivity1_HfSelectedId');
        if (actElement) actElement.value = '154';
        // Employee input element
        let emplElement = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_CphContentWrapper_CphMainContent_DocumentEditor_SelectEmployee_HfSelectedId');
        if (emplElement) emplElement.value = '%7B%22id%22%3A%221386%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22Employee%22%7D';
        // Input element for description (assuming this is where paste happens)
        let aboutElement = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_CphContentWrapper_CphMainContent_DocumentEditor_info_About');
        if (aboutElement) {
            // Add event listener for paste event
            aboutElement.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
                // Prevent the default paste behavior
                e.preventDefault();
                // Get pasted data
                let clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
                let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');
                // Set the value of aboutElement
                aboutElement.value = pastedText;
                // Save as working document
                let saveButton = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_CphContentWrapper_CphMainContent_DocumentEditor_BtnSaveAsWorking');
                if (saveButton) saveButton.click();
            });
        }
    }
}


AFAIK you'll have to write an extension with clipboardRead permission and this site in host_permissions, then you can use document.execcommand('paste').

even if you could read the clipboard, how would that eliminate user input? the user still needs to copy the data?

@GTK VBA takes care of that part.

what are you trying to do exactly? why not post the data to the server directly?

@GTK I'm a regular user, so I can't do that. Just trying to lazy mod some boring repetitive tasks.

you should explain in more detail where the data comes from and where it goes, and where does the automation start? there may be ways to post the data even as a user.
